# Correlation between Y and (x1, x2)

Tags: regression, correlation

I'm studying regression models based on Larson R. Applied Statistics for a problem involving wind speed prediction.

To predict wind speed I used atmospheric pressure and humidity.
When I do the correlation - Pearson - between wind speed and atmospheric pressure, I found the value of 0,077 and 0,025 between wind speed and humidity.

But, when I model wind speed with a multiple linear regression, I found a correlation value of 0,979.

Is it possible to calculate the correlation between one variable and two or more variables?

With regression models is possible - seems to be -, but there are other way?

Comment: I agree that those three values don't seem to go together. I suspect you've made a computational mistake. Can you provide the raw data in a machine-readable format?

Comment: Yes, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zDo0SY6Qb3oRokQc9ZLh2fyP_wnv-zkf

Answer (score 1):

It indeed seems that you miscomputed something. My calculations for the two pairwise correlations agree with yours, but when I fit the regression model `` lm(`Wind Speed` ~ `Atmospheric Pressure` + `Humidity`) `` in R, I get an $R^2$ of .024, or .036 if you add an interaction term. Taking the square roots of these $R^2$s to produce coefficients of multiple correlation, I get 0.155 and 0.189.

Comment: Well, you're right xD. Thanks, that's what happend, i miscomputed something. I used Excel multiple linear regression. But, know I'm inquisitive about this: to predict the wind speed velocity, 7,7% of the value can be explained by the atmospheric pressure and 2,5% of the value can be explained by the humidity. And the rest due to other factors?

Comment: @user4642 No, for that kind of question, you want the $R^2$ from the full model. For example, the $R^2$ of .036 for the model with an interaction term means that 3.6% of the variation in wind speed is explained by atmospheric pressure and humidity.

Comment: Understood, I'm very greatful for your response. Thanks